# azure trigger different branch push

Tags: git, azure, visual-c++

I am using azure pipeline. Here is what i need:

When something is pushed to master, i want it to run the build process and move artifacts to /production.

When something is pushed to staging, i want it to run the build process and move artifacts to /staging.

I have one yaml file. I don't want to have different pipelines.

So, Let's say I have something like this in that yaml.

- trigger:

  ```
  master
  staging
  ```

Now, this would work, but I also need to set env variables depending on the master branch or staging branch since those branches tell which one is for production and which one for staging.

I couldn't find any way to do this unless I use a script section and switch statement something like this:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
displayName: Determine source branch
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
switch(${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH}) {
'refs/heads/master' {Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=admiralBaseUri]https://admiral-p.azurefd.net"; }
'refs/heads/development' {Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=admiralBaseUri]https://admiral-d.azurefd.net"; }
default {Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=admiralBaseUri]NONE"; }
}
```

Question: Is there any way that's better than this approach? how do you handle these kind of situations?